Unable to get user to register with a different Spotify Account
In this flutter project I gave an option for users to register with their spotify accounts which works but once their spotify account is linked with my project whenever they click register with spotify they directly go to profile page. In this moment I wanted to add a mid screen asking if they want to continue with their account or go back to register screen and register with a different spotify account but I was unable to do that. Waiting for your help. I want to access the not you screen once user presses no button if they want to continue
My Spotify Register Screen:
dart
class _SpotifyLoginWebViewState extends State<SpotifyLoginWebView> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Spotify Login', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
        backgroundColor: Colors.black,
      ),
      body: WebView(
        javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
        initialUrl: widget.url,
        navigationDelegate: (NavigationRequest request) async {
          if (request.url.startsWith(redirectUri)) {
            final Uri uri = Uri.parse(request.url);
            final String? code = uri.queryParameters['code'];

            if (code != null) {
              final String accessToken = await getAccessToken(code);
              final userInfo = await getUserInfo(accessToken);
              final username = userInfo['display_name'];
              final email = userInfo['email'];

              bool userExists = await checkEmailExists(email);
              if (!userExists) {
                await createInWithEmailAndPassword(
                  email: email,
                  password: 'your_default_password',
                  username: username,
                  age: 0,
                );
              }

              Navigator.push(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SpotifyMidScreen(username: username, email: email, accessToken: accessToken)),
              );
            } else {
              throw Exception('Authorization code not found');
            }
          }
          return NavigationDecision.navigate;
        },
      ),
    );
  }

My access operations:
dart
 Future<String> getAccessToken(String code) async {
    final response = await http.post(
      Uri.parse(tokenEndpoint),
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'Authorization': 'Basic ${base64Encode(utf8.encode('$clientId:$clientSecret'))}',
      },
      body: {
        'grant_type': 'authorization_code',
        'code': code,
        'redirect_uri': redirectUri,
      },
    );

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      final jsonResponse = json.decode(response.body);
      return jsonResponse['access_token'];
    } else {
      print('Failed to get access token with status: ${response.statusCode}');
      throw Exception('Failed to get access token: ${response.body}');
    }
  }



  Future<Map<String, dynamic>> getUserInfo(String accessToken) async {
    final response = await http.get(
      Uri.parse('https://api.spotify.com/v1/me'),
      headers: {'Authorization': 'Bearer $accessToken'},
    );

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      return json.decode(response.body);
    } else {
      throw Exception('Failed to get user info: ${response.body}');
    }
  }

And the mid screen I implemented:
dart
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      extendBodyBehindAppBar: true,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Welcome!', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
      ),
      body: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          gradient: LinearGradient(
            begin: Alignment.topRight,
            end: Alignment.bottomLeft,
            colors: [Colors.deepPurple.shade400, Colors.indigo.shade800],
          ),
        ),
        child: Center(
          child: ListView(children: [
            Text(
              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              'Would you like to continue as ' + widget.username + '?',
              style: GoogleFonts.lato(
                fontSize: 20,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                color: Colors.black,
              ),
            ),
            Row(
              children: [
                Expanded(
                  child: ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed: () async {
                      await signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: widget.email, password: 'your_default_password');

                      Navigator.push(
                        context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => ProfileScreen()),
                      );
                    },
                    style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                      foregroundColor: Colors.white70,
                      backgroundColor: Colors.purple.shade700,
                      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 50, vertical: 12),
                      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                      ),
                    ),
                    child: Text("YES"),
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: ElevatedButton(
                    onPressed: () async {
                      await FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut();
                      await signOutFromSpotify();
                      Navigator.push(
                        context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => MyHomePage(width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width, height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height)),
                      );
                    },
                    style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                      foregroundColor: Colors.white70,
                      backgroundColor: Colors.purple.shade700,
                      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 50, vertical: 12),
                      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                      ),
                    ),
                    child: Text("NO"),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ]),
        ),
      ),
    );

I tried revoking token but it didn't work it gave me 404 error:
dart
Future<void> signOutFromSpotify(String accessToken) async {
    final response = await http.post(
      Uri.parse('https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token/revoke'),
      headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Basic ${base64Encode(utf8.encode('$clientId:$clientSecret'))}',
      },
      body: {
        'token': accessToken,
      },
    );
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      print('Access token revoked');
    } else {
      print('Failed to revoke access token: ${response.statusCode}');
    }
  }

I tried also unlinking process from Spotify web api's document but it didn't work either maybe I did it wrong:
dart
 Future<void> signOutFromSpotify(String accessToken) async {
    final response = await http.post(
      Uri.parse('https://open-access.spotify.com/api/v1/unlink-user'),
      headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ${base64Encode(utf8.encode('$clientId:$clientSecret'))}',
      },
      body: {
        'token': accessToken,
      },
    );
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      print('Access token revoked');
    } else {
      print('Failed to revoke access token: ${response.statusCode}');
    }
  }


error 401 and also tried this version:
dart
Future<void> signOutFromSpotify(String accessToken) async {
    final response = await http.post(
      Uri.parse('https://open-access.spotify.com/api/v1/unlink-user'),
      headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ${accessToken}',
      },
      body: {
        'token': accessToken,
      },
    );
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      print('Access token revoked');
    } else {
      print('Failed to revoke access token: ${response.statusCode}');
    }
  }


gave the error 403
I've also tried shared_preferences but it didn't work either:
dart
Future<void> signOutFromSpotify() async {
    final SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    await prefs.remove('accessToken');
    print('Spotify access token cleared locally.');
  }

